# Twitter image upload using java script.

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth, image-uploading

I am trying to upload a image to twitter via https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json API provided by twitter.

I am really confused about the flow for calling this API. How will I get user authenticate and allow my application to post data ? 
Can anyone give me the exact steps to follow for implementing this ? If any one having sample code for the same that will be most helpful.

If there is any library available for then please direct me to it.

Regards

Comment: A bit detailed but will give you an idea of how oAuth works http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/dancing-with-oauth-understanding-how-authorization-works/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this from javascript client code? I had to do that recently, and you're going to have to user server-side code, for two reasons:

1. You may have to store tokens in your client code. Which would be a security hole.
2. Twitter API no longer allows cross-browser requests, as their responses don't include 'access-control-allow-origin' headers, so you won't be able to call them via AJAX.